# Why are my PNGs ugly in Codename One?

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I'm excited to roll out my first codename one app but I'm running into issues with the look of the program. On Netbeans my images great and my label backgrounds are appropriate. However, on my tablet, images have a background and my labels look odd.

The tablet image is from a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3.

Any idea how to fix this?

(Since SO won't allow me to post images, here is a link to the screenshots: http://www.pricepasta.com/random/Uglypng.jpg)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I really like that logo!

Comment: what about in the android emulator? how does it look there?

Comment: The android emulator is shown. It looks great in there. I'm going to try Shai's suggestion and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Android build argument `android.asyncPaint=true` to use the newer rendering pipeline.

You would also need to test in the Android simulator to see the misalignment on the simulator as well. I'm assuming this is triggered by misuse of the layout managers.